# Facebook invite with facebook SDK 3 for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, sdk

since the Facebook SDK for iOS has changes I was wondering what is the best way to invite a friend to the app. The documentation on their developers website seems to be a bit old.

I already have a custom friendPicker running on my app, just need to set an action when the user hits his/her friend.

Any ideas or examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [send Facebook apprequests with the facebook SDK 3](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11578198/send-facebook-apprequests-with-the-facebook-sdk-3)

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495462/presentrequestsdialogmodallywithsession-does-not-work-but-gives-good-result/16654666#16654666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use facebook old SDK along with the new one and followed their tutorial for invites.

Note that you cant use the same SDK on the same .m, so be carefull.